# Untangling and merging branches with previous commits

Tags: git

I have an upstream git repository (remote) that has a master and several branches but only one of the branches is important for the discussion at hand:

upstream:

```
x-------y--------> master
     \
      \
        ----z-----> develX
```

I then have my own repo cloned from upstream at x.

```
x--------y---------> master
      \
       \
        -----z-------> develY
```

develY is my branch with my own work and patches (z) from develX. My master is slightly lost in time. It has patches (y) from upstream master and some tweaks to try to get it to work with some of my patches but it's actually a lost case and not working.

So I decided to make it exactly the same as develY with:
    $ git checkout develY
    $ git merge -s ours master
    $ git checkout master
    $ git merge develY
    $ git push

So now master is exactly the same as develY. However, what I really want is to sync my master to upstream master with my changes from develY (which are now also in my master).

I initially thought I am going to rebase changes in upstream master onto my master, however there are about 6000 commits upstream to rebase and there's no way this is going to work well. There are several issues that seem to make this case more complex than I initially thought:

- develY (and master after my merge and push of master) has some patches from upstream develX which might not exist in upstream master;
- my master has some commits from upstream master that were reverted due to the merge -s ours of develY;
- due to the point above, `git merge-base master upstream/master` shows patch y as last common ancestor however this patch is not actually in master because it was reverted with the merge.

Any suggestions on how to as cleanly as possible get my master synced with upstream/master and the changes from my develY?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do a `git merge origin/master` from in `master`.

When you say 'no way going to work out' what do you mean?  There are two many conflicts?  If there are true conflict and you want both sets of changes then you really do have to resolve them by manual editing.

`git rebase` is the route I take anyway so that I `git fetch` the newest master and then rebase my work on top of it and resolve the conflicts that come up.  I frequently use `git rebase -i HEAD~10` first to squash/reorder/delete my branch commits first.

Comment: You mean `git merge upstream/master` from `master`?

Comment: The reason I say the rebase is not going to work out well is because in origin/master I have some (but not all) patches of upstream/master up to one point plus my own work. As a result trying to rebase patches from upstream means that there will be conflicts for almost all of the rebase attempts.